# Azure AD Msal Interceptor Access Token

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, azure-active-directory, msal-angular

I'm using azure MSAL to authenticate my API but problem is that I'm using DevExtreme custom store for server side pagination.

Msal Interceptor works and genrate token auto for HttpClient but in this case I'm not sending request via http.

If I'm using access token that I get after login then error occur Invalid signature and if If used IdToken then 401 how I can solve this problem.

MSALInterceptorConfigFactory:

```
protectedResourceMap.set('https://localhost:44379/api/approveMilestones', ['api://cb343c76-cd5b-4af6-8229-014b2522adab/access_as_user']);
```

Login Response where I'm getting accessToken and IdToken

```
this.authService.loginPopup()
  .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
    AuthenticationHelper.setToken(response.accessToken);
    this.router.navigate(['/payments-approval']);
  });
```

[I'm getting accessToken and IdTOken both in result but these are not working if i send them with request for Bearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppoEv.png)

Comment: If you check the access token at https://jwt.ms, what is the "aud" (audience) value?

Comment: aud value is same which is my clientID

Comment: Ok, that sounds correct. How is your back-end authentication configured?

Comment: Backend authentication is good and i tested it but problem is that I'm not dealing with http request for some API's.

Comment: Is there any way in angular that we may get bearer token from browser ?

Answer (score -1):

While sending the request to the server the scopes are empty when going the cross-domain. You can create your own interceptor from small-angular and then you can inject the code in development mode.

First store the token in the localStorage:

`localStorage.setItem ('token', result.token);`

While sending the request to the server get the token from the browser

`const token = localStorage.getItem (‘token');`
and send the token with the request like this.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code).